# y-axis is messy when graphing

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm having trouble graphing in python. The data is in a dataframe and is 2 columns. The problem is that when graphing, the "y-axis" is disordered, it does not go from the origin (0, 0) to the maximum value which would be ~4. This is the code of the table:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
datosg = pd.DataFrame()
datosg = nochetotal[["Hour", "UV Index"]]
print(datosg)
```

and this is what it throws as a result:

```
       Hour UV Index
32709    19    3.155
32710    19    0.197
32711    19    0.158
32712    19    0.158
32713    19    0.197
...     ...      ...
33424     6    0.592
33425     6    0.592
33426     6    0.473
33427     6    0.592
33428     6    0.473

[720 rows x 2 columns]
```

If I make the graph of Hour vs. UV Index, The y-axis is very messy and meaningless:

```
x_v = datosg["Hour"]
y_v = datosg["UV Index"]
plt.figure(figsize = (20,10))

#nochetotal.plot("Hour", "UV Index", kind="scatter")
plt.plot(x_v, y_v, color = 'g', marker = 'o')
plt.xlabel('Hour')
plt.ylabel('Indice UV')
plt.title('Indice UV ')
plt.show()
```

[image: This is the resulting graph]

I don't understand what you are doing wrong...

Comment: What does `datosg.dtypes` return?

Comment: This is what it returns:

Series([], dtype: object)

Comment: Your data are not numeric.

Comment: Oh, so how do I convert my table values ​​to numeric values? Please. The solution you gave me didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can happen when your data is not a numeric type, but is made up of strings (regardless of whether the strings contain numbers). try using [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html), i.e.:

```py
nochetotal["Hour"] = pd.to_numeric(nochetotal["Hour"])
nochetotal["UV Index"] = pd.to_numeric(nochetotal["UV Index"])
```

Comment: I get the following error:

TypeError: arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series

Comment: oh oops. you may need to call this on each column separately

Comment: Thank you! This solved the type of values ​​that are in the columns and it was able to graph well. The output of the datosg.dtypes command gave: Hour          int64
UV Index    float64
dtype: object

Comment: great! just noting that I am not `BigBen`, who first correctly identified the issue and suggested you diagnose it with `datosg.dtypes`